# How to choose projection for @RepositoryRestResource call

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'd like to make a call to a repository annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource` using a projection. The repository has no excerpt projection.

Calling `/teams/1?projection=summary`, I get the data using the specified projection.

Calling `/teams?projection=summary`, it is not using any projection. How can I ensure, that it uses the right projection?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the query parameter based solution is just working for item resources and not the collection resource. One thing you can do is to use an excerpt projection for your repository. So whenever your resource is embedded the projection is applied. And this applies to collections.

You can specify the excerpt using the `@RepositoryRestResource` like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = SummaryProjection.class)
```

See the documentation for details:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The excerpt projection limits the application to use only one projection for all the listings. Instead, I would like to use several projections for listings and not always the same.

Comment: I got that - but what you require just does not seem to be supported.